# Fade edge with custom ListItems

Tags: android

**EDIT: Solved** I am developing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, which has some version of TouchWiz. I tried my application on a device running stock android 3.x and it faded the items correctly.

**Original Post:**
I am wondering why my `ListView` is not fading the top or bottom of my list. I have a feeling that because I have made a custom `ListItem`, that it ignores any fading that the `ListView` is trying to do.

I have tried:

- manually setting fading edge to `vertical` for moth the `ListItem` and the `ListView`
- setting the fading edge length to some value to see if it was defaulting to 0 for some reason.

Is there something I need to implement in my `ListItem` to allow it to fade properly? Here is a picture of my `ListItem`. It has a 9-patch background image, a few `TextView`s, and a `ProgressBar`. Some of the `TextView`s have a custom font applied to them in code.

[image: My custom ListItem]

Comment: I have a similar problem with the gallery. There is no fading edge displayed at the left side of my first gallery item and none on the right side of my last gallery item. For the items in between the fading edge displays just fine...

Comment: Please put the solution in it's own answer and accept it, so that this question can move out of the unanswered tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**: I am developing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, which has some version of TouchWiz. I tried my application on a device running stock android 3.x and it faded the items correctly.